# Lock/Retry vs Exception flow

Tags: java, database, multithreading, locking

I am working on a new project where I have to implement something like a createOrGetFromDB method which would be thread safe.

Basically, I am getting a request to create a row in the DB after doing some validations. If the row already exists(exist decision by a unique key), I have to return the row instead. There is quite a bit of chance that I can get multiple same requests at the same time, so my implementation has to be thread safe.

After brainstorming a bit, I think I have two options:

- Create a method which would lock using the unique key by storing into cache and checking if key is present in cache or not. If present, wait and try to get from DB after a certain interval(maybe 500 ms?)
- Let the method try to insert into DB and let the unique constraint handle whether to save or not. I just check if exception happens while saving and process accordingly.

Are there any pros/cons going with either of the flows? Or a better way to handle this flow?

I am doing this in Java if that helps? (I heard Java exception handling consumes quite a bit of CPU?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that you will have to handle the second case _anyway_ (because of the possibility of multiple copies of the server running).

Comment: I was planning on using a distributed cache to save the lock which hopefully should solve this issue

Comment: IMO, the only good way is to use features of your underlying storage. For example, if you have a unique restriction on some specific fields, this will prevent you from duplicates. A distributed cache... It's possible, but this may increase operation cost and make your insertion slower significantly